# How Do Databases Achieve (Relatively) Quick Updates On Existing Records And Queries On Those Updates?

Tags: database

For databases like Postgres and ElasticSearch, updates to existing records are relatively quick. I understand that for these databases, when an update on an existing record is written, the physical location for the existing record isn't updated at that moment, but instead the change is written to an append-only file that can be queried until it is persisted.

For example:

```
-- First Select
SELECT name FROM people WHERE id = 100000;

-- The Update
UPDATE people SET name = "Joe" Where id = 100000;

-- Second Select
SELECT name FROM people WHERE id = 100000;
```

It's my understanding that `The Update` will write this change to an append-only file, and during the `Second Select` it will use that append-only file to get the latest name. After some time, `The Update` will be persisted and removed from the append-only file.

With this is mind, it makes sense that these "updates" can be fast, because they are just inserting new data into the end of a file, but how is querying that data still fast?

If I implemented a similar idea in tables themselves, I would need to use a window function over the combination of both tables and float the most recent changes forward. This would be very slow, but Postgres and ElasticSearch achieves this transparently without any noticeable performance impacts.

How does this work?

Comment: The actual computational cost of what you describe is not high when data is cleverly structured. The mechanics will be specific to a DB engine, but moving all references from the old to the new row could be just a case of updating a single pointer. Keeping multiple versions of a row, and accessing the one appropriate to the transactional context, also isn't necessarily expensive at low rates of concurrency. The database could also queue and serialise competing transactions, so that ultimately there aren't multiple copies of a row actually outstanding at once, just the current committed one.

Answer (score 4):

The DBMS run some kind of optimizer on queries, to decide the best access strategy.

For your `SELECT`, if the `id` column is indexed, the system will use that index and need less than 20 reads to find one row among a million. Probably, the optimizer will also make use of some cache checking if the record is still in memory.

For your `UPDATE`, there are many techniques as well. One common technique uses some kind of paging: the updated data is written in the DB at a new location, but is kept private to the transaction performing the update. During that time, all the other transactions still read the old value. Once the transaction is committed, the location of the record is updated to refer to the new record, and the old will be discarded at the next occasion.

But these are just examples. Every DBMS technology and implementation has its own techniques and tricks. There are full books on how DBmS work internally, and the space for this answer is far too small to cover them all.